# Spring dblink and invoke trigger on another database

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Hi there I would ask you about recommended solutions of connecting another database in Spring + Hibernate.

In my case I have small application with its database and what I need to do is to obtain some data from another (large) db. 
Currently I'm doing that with postgresql and *dblink* but now it would be better to move this query into code. 
In near future I'll also need to invoke triggers on that database.

So the question is whats the best practice to solve this kind of connection problems?

To sum up, what I need:

- invoke another database trigger
- invoke dblink and obtain data from another database

Comment: I have never done it through spring but : couldn't you use a foreign data wrapper ? https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/querying-external-data-from-postgresql-using-jdbc-fdw

Comment: Yes I'm kind of using it(dblink) but now I'm wondering what is the best way to implement it into code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to invoke another database from your spring boot application. So your base application will use MySQL and the secondary database will be Postgres.

1. If you are using `spring-boot` then create `lib` folder under the project folder (Same hierarchy of `src`). Add required `jdbc` jar in that folder.
2. Then, create DataBaseConfig class with `@Configuration`, inside that class create `ComboPooledDataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` bean.
3. Now in your service class just do Autowiring of that JdbcTemplate bean. Then, write SQL query to get value using this method `queryForList`
4. In pom.xml, you can map that external jar file like below

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
       <version>11.1</version>
       <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/mysql.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>


   @Configuration
   public class DatabaseConfig {

   @Bean(name = "employeeDataBase")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "employee.datasource")
   public ComboPooledDataSource employeeDataSource() {
       return new ComboPooledDataSource();
   }

   @Bean(name = "employeeTemplate")
   public JdbcTemplate employeeTemplate(@Qualifier("employeeDataBase") DataSource ds) {
       return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
   }
   }

   @Service
   public class EmployeeService {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("employeeTemplate")
   JdbcTemplate employeeTemplate;

   public void getEmployeeFromExternalDB() {
       List<Map<String, Object>> maps = employeeTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE");
   }
   }

   //application.properties
   employee.datasource.jdbc-url=${EMPLOYEE_URL}
   employee.datasource.user=${EMPLOYEE_UNAME}
   employee.datasource.password=${EMPLOYEE_PWD}
   employee.datasource.driver-class=com.edb.Driver
   employee.datasource.max-idle-time=6
   employee.datasource.min-pool-size=3
   employee.datasource.max-pool-size=15
   employee.datasource.jdbcUrl=${EMPLOYEE_URL}
   employee.datasource.driver-class-name=com.edb.Driver
   ```